# C++ futures parallel processing

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using `std::futures` to parallel process my algorithm. I split up the information into mutually exclusive pools and then perform the same operation on each pool in its own thread. The code looks like this:

```
class Processor
{
public:
    Processor(const std::string &strVal) : m_strVal(strVal)
    {
    }

    std::string GetVal() const {return m_strVal;}

    std::vector<std::string> Do()
    {
        // do some processing - this can throw an exception
    }

private:
    std::string m_strVal;
};

class ParallelAlgo
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_vecMasterResults;

public:

    ProcessingFunction(const std::vector<std::string> &vecInfo)
    {
        // vecInfo holds mutually exclusive pools

        std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::string> > > vecFutures(vecInfo.size());

        try
        {
            for (auto n = 0 ; n < vecInfo.size() ; n++)
            {
                vecFuture[n] = std::async(std::launch::async, &ParallelAlgo::WorkFunc, vecInfo[n].GetVal());
            }

            for (auto it = vecFutures.begin() ; it != vecFutures.end() ; ++it)
            {
                std::vector<std::string> RetVal = it->get();
                m_MasterResults.insert(m_MasterResults.begin(), RetVal.begin(), RetVal.end());
                vecFutures.erase(it);
            }
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            for (auto it = vecFutures.begin() ; it != vecFuture.end() ; ++it)
            {
                // race condition?
                if (it->valid())
                {
                    it->wait_for(std::chrono::second(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> ParallelAlgo::WorkFunc(const std::string &strVal)
    {
        Processor _Proccessor(strVal);
        return _Processor.Do();
    }
};
```

My question is how to handle the situation when an exception is thrown in `Processor:Do()`? Currently I catch the exception using a `future`, and then wait zero seconds for each `future` that hasn't finished; this is fine - these threads will simply terminate and the processing will not be completed. However, have I not introduced a race condition in the catch block. a `future` could finish between the calls to `valid()` and `wait_for()`, or is this not a concern as I'm not calling `get()` on these incomplete futures?

Comment: Calling `wait_for` on a finished `thread` works exactly as one would expect, it returns immediately. I don't see the problem.

Comment: As you do nothing with the exception, couldn't you just not worry about unfinished threads? Destructors of the `std::future` will block until async processing finish, if necessary, but as far as I understand that is what you want.

Comment: There is a bug in the example code. Calling `vecFutures.erase(it);` will invalidate `it` and further using it in the for loop is UB.

Comment: I just asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246665/when-one-worker-thread-fails-how-to-abort-remaining-workers.  In my case, I *want* all still-executing async tasks to be stopped when an error occurs.  It's not clear from your question whether you also want that, or whether you're happy to wait for remaining tasks to complete.

Answer (score 3):

A call to `valid` only checks if there is a corresponding shared state, which will still be true for a finished thread until you call `get` on it.

There is no race condition there.